# Where to ask about Google Play seller refunds?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is the following: I'm planning to create a free app as a beta, where a certain amount of people will be able to join as "beta testers" (say 100 for example). After the application is tested and working fine I would like to release the fee/paid versions of that app, but giving the testers the paid version for free.

I don't think Google provide tools for that, but I'm wondering if I do a manual refund, will the user be able to get future updates? What is the best way to do that?

---

I'm not sure where to ask this question as on [Android SE FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> **off-topic**:
>
> [...]
> Issues with the Android Market from the point of view of a developer or publisher
> [...]

Comment: there might not be anywhere to ask inside SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there are really any sites in the SE network that will accept your question currently. [There is a proposal in the commitment phase for an App Stores SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores), so if/when that hits beta your question would presumably be on-topic there.

Aside from that, you can try using [Google's Play Support](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601) site and Help Center to contact them directly.

Comment: Thanks! I tried many times to contact Google's Play Support.. and all I received is template responses and no information about my question. I'll follow that proposal you said.. Thanks!